# мне нужен код функции strtr() я cмог написать вот:

Tags: php

> я написал функцию strtr()
> если кому надо то вот:

```
public static function strtr($text, $from, $to){
        $newText = '';
        $zam = [];
        $text_arr = [];
        if (strlen($from) !== strlen($to)) return false;
        for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($from); $i++) {
            $zam[$from[$i]] = $to[$i];
        }
        for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($text); $i++) { 
            $text_arr[] = $text[$i];
        }
        foreach ($text_arr as $char) { 
            if (isset($zam[$char])){
                $newText .= $zam[$char];
            } else {
                $newText .= $char;
            }
        }
        return $newText;
    }
```

Comment: и с какой проблемой вы столкнулись то?

Comment: результат, не совпадает